# Как изменить способ появления текста toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

Возникло несколько вопросов по такой реализации спойлера.

Как изменить то как появляется текст при помощи toggle(), что бы он появлялся сверху вниз, а не слева-сверху в право-вниз?

И как убрать подчеркивание у активного спойлера?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spoiler_links').click(function() {
    $('.spoiler_body').hide(500);
    $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('normal');
    return false;
  });
  $('.spoiler_links1').click(function() {
    $('.spoiler_body1').hide(500);
    $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body1').toggle('normal');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler_body,
.spoiler_body1 {
  display: none;
}
.spoiler_links,
.spoiler_links1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6B8841;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #6B8841;
}
.act {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
p {
  color: #6B8841;
}
td {
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links1"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body1">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links1"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body1">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7L42g6w7/1/

Comment: @soledar10, почему в ответ не пишешь?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spoiler_links').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    $('.spoiler_links_current').removeClass('spoiler_links_current');      
    $(this).toggleClass('spoiler_links_current');    
    $('.spoiler_body').slideUp();   
    $(this).next().slideDown();   
  });  
});
```

```css
td {
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.spoiler_body{
  display: none;
  color: #6B8841;
}
.spoiler_links{  
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6B8841;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #6B8841;
}
.spoiler_links_current {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="spoiler_links"><strong>спойлер</strong></a>
          <div class="spoiler_body">
            <p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст тексттекст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```